# Error while compiling Nexus grouper kernel in Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, linux, rom, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying to build a `ROM` from `AOSP 5.1.1` specifically (`Nexus 7 Wifi 2012` - grouper) .However, a while ago I got stuck at this part while building the kernel

The following command works fine:

```
make tegra3_android_defconfig
```

The problem starts when I write:

```
 make -j4
```

It crashes and says

```
Fahads-MBP:tegra Fahad$ make -j4
/volumes/untitled/tegra/../WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: /volumes/untitled/tegra/../WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: cannot execute binary file
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  UPD     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  Generating include/generated/mach-types.h
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/bin/sh: /volumes/untitled/tegra/../WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: cannot execute binary file
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 126
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2

#### make failed to build some targets (2 seconds) ####
```

I do have a 2015 MAC which is a 64-bit machine using Darwin. Can you suggest what I did wrong, what could be the reason for this error or where I can get help for this problem?

Comment: Check the executable permission of `/volumes/untitled/tegra/../WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-gcc` file

Comment: @deimus I have given every user read and write permissions for the files but still its giving the same errors

Comment: Read write permissions don't mean execution permission.

Comment: @deimus I ran the following command chmod 777 arm-eabi-gcc. That should cover read, write and execute?

Comment: also the following command 
chmod +x arm-eabi-gcc